# How to Run kubectl command to gke from github without service account

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, config, github-actions, credentials, client-certificates

I have to run kubectl apploy -f pod1.yml (as a example) from my github action. So to provide GKE credentials to github one way is by configuring service account key as a gihub repo secret. But I dont have permission to create service key also I will not getting permission to create. So I tried to create a user by createing certificates like username.key, username.csr. After that when I am going to sign the username.csr with ca.crt and ca.key then I am unable to find ca.crt and ca.key in my gke cluster. ( nothing inside here - /etc/kubernetes/pki/ ).

1. So now my question is how to sign username.csr with ca.crt and ca.key inside GKE?
2. If I cant sign then what is other options to run kubectl command from github action to GKE? (except service account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use Workload Identity Federation which removes the need for storing Service Account JSON keys. This is a GitHub action for using Workload Identity Federation: https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth